# What is the SINR unit of the reception probability equation in AWGN?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$P_s(SINR_{threshhold}) = exp((-SINR_{threshhold}(r_{rx})^{\alpha}\rho^2)/P)$

$P_s(SINR_{threshhold})$ is reception probability according to SINR threshold. $\alpha$ is loss exponent and $\rho^2$ is noise variance in AWGN. $r_{rx}$ is the distance between the receiver and the transmitter. $P$ is the transmission power. I think the unit of power is W. But I don't know what the unit of SINR is. dB? or W? For example, when SINR threshhold is 8dB, if unit is dB, $SINR_{threshhold}$ is 8. But if the unit is W, it will be $10^8$.  How can I find it?

Thank you

Comment: I jotted a quick explanation. Not sure if it answers your question. This question may be a better fit at our sister site dedicated to Electrical Engineering. There are more qualifiied (than yours truly) people haunting that site. But, you should familiarize yourself with what they expect from askers. And, if you end up posting there, you must cross-link the two variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNR stands for *signal-to-noise-ratio*. If you discuss SINR instead, then it reads (not 100% about the details) *signal-to-interference-and-noise-ratio*.

Anyway, both signal power and noise power (and also the power of the interfering signal from other users) is measured in Watts. But, this implies that their *ratio* has units Watts/Watts, in other words, a plain number. The relevant scale is logarithmic so this is more often than not coverted into decibels. So if the power of the (useful) signal is $X$ (Watts) and 
interference+noise combine to power $Y$, then
$$
\text{SINR}=10\cdot\log_{10}\frac{X}{Y}\,\text{dB}.
$$
Because it is in *deci*bels, we multiply the logarithm of the ratio by ten.

---

Remember that the energy of a harmonic oscillator (like a radio wave) is proportional to the square of the amplitude. Squaring doubles the logarithm, so if you give $X$ and $Y$ in terms of the amplitudes as opposed to Watts (may happen naturally, if you do a simulation), then you need to multiply by two.

---

But, **A Big But**. Looking at the formula you gave it looks like it requires the actual SINR. NOT THE LOG-SCALED VERSION ABOVE. So the unit will be Watts/Watts, a plain number. Not the log-scale version measured in decibels.

Comment: Thank you. There was the my calculation mistake.